# How do I give dungeons sensible layouts that are still gameable?

Tags: map-making, maps, dungeon-design

When creating dungeons, I like to try to give them a history beyond "old place with traps and monsters and gold", since I like everything to feel real and have a purpose. However, whenever I try to map out one of these, they either end up with planning that doesn't make sense for what it is, or wouldn't be fun to play through.

How do I create a dungeon layout that has/had purpose and would still be fun and challenging to explore?

Comment: @GreySage I was looking for general advice. I plan on having a very wide variety of dungeons and environments, but if you wanna give advice pertaining to a specific place, something like a jungle temple will likely be the next dungeons my players go to!

Comment: You may be interested in this question: [How to create a dungeon based on a realistic tomb, but still enjoyable to explore?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48785/8610).

Comment: Does the system you're playing have dungeon-creation advice?

Comment: It would help if we knew specifically what it is that makes your dungeons feel like they don't make sense, and what it is that makes your sensible dungeons not fun?

Comment: @okeefe - I'm not sure that's relevant. In my experience, the dungeon-creation advice in most systems is focused entirely on the game mechanics, making them "balanced", providing appropriate rewards, etc. with little or no mention of making them feel plausible. The sort of advice the OP is looking for tends to be in (usually third-party) supplements rather than the core system.

Comment: @DaveSherohman It's a major failing if the game expects dungeons and doesn't provide rules for gameable dungeons. Maybe the results aren't “sensible” according to the asker? It's hard to answer this in a system-neutral way, in my opinion.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'll second that **this question should just be merged with that one**, since it has far better answers that comprehensively address OP's concerns. (This question would be distinct if it weren't solely about dungeons but, since it is, the current answer about house floor plans is actually completely off-topic.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Use real-world maps.

If you're really interested in verisimilitude, you can look at floor plans from the internet. For example, if I wanted to make a manor, I could do a bit of googling and find a floor plan [like this](https://www.archivaldesigns.com/home-plans/chateau-novella-house-plan), which looks like it could make for a decent house-based dungeon crawl:

[image]

Alternatively, if you wanted to have some ancient temple or tomb, you could look for similar things in the real world. The Great Pyramid near Giza, Egypt has a layout somewhat [like this](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-inside-the-great-pyramid):

[image]

### Sometimes stuff just doesn't make sense

When I plan dungeons, I sometimes try to make sensible dungeons, where each room has a purpose. But honestly, I don't feel like many people really care about that: I've never heard someone ask, "but what is the original purpose of this room?" Because you're ultimately planning for a game that is fun, "making sense" kind of falls by the wayside.

Depending on the kind of game you're playing, you have access to lots of things the real world doesn't. I've run a sprawling, multiroom dungeon with infinite floors before. None of the rooms make any sense from a usability or architectural standpoint, but my excuse was "a mad god did it". If you think a certain structure can be fun to play, you can just insert it and come up with a justification later.

Finally, if you want a real-world example of dungeon-like buildings that are full of real purpose and history but make no sense, look to the Winchester House in California. From Wikipedia:

> Since its construction in 1884, the property and mansion were claimed by many to be haunted by the ghosts of those killed with Winchester rifles. Under Winchester's day-to-day guidance, its "from-the-ground-up" construction proceeded around the clock, by some accounts, without interruption, until her death on September 5, 1922, at which time work immediately ceased.

It looks something like this:

> [image]

Doesn't that sound like a great place to run a dungeon?

Comment: Too bad there isn't a comprehensive source of floor plans for actual medieval castles and fortresses.  Unfortunately, in reality, the donjon below many of these keeps was nothing more than a hole in the ground.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Why does it need to be comprehensive? For the purposes of playing game, anything that even looks somewhat reasonable should work, right?

Comment: Well, okay, but (for instance) the book *Castle*, which details the construction of a real-world river keep, just covers *one* castle keep.  There doesn't seem to be a reference work with interior layouts of a bunch of castles, towers, fortresses, and dungeons?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Sounds like a business opportunity.

Comment: If only I weren't already employed full time at something that pays now, rather than in a year (or several) when it's done, providing it actually sells...

Comment: Another such location is Bishop Castle in Colorado: http://www.bishopcastle.org/.  Generally speaking any "folly" might be a good model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Folly_buildings_in_the_United_States

Comment: Most of the real buildings are not perfectly logical in their design. I have been in a school with a place that you could only reach by going two floors underground and then going up again after taking different corridors, and it was a commonly used building, not some ancient crumbling place.

Comment: I've had fun before introducing a familiar location that all the players know of in real life, and presenting it as a dungeon. There's a certain amount of joy in seeing the lightbulb click on in the players' eyes when they realize they know where they are.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. Some very rare/exceptional examples aside real-world-based maps would IMHO make for bad/boring dungeons. To give one issue I see: real cellars / graves / dungeons aren't labyrinthian but designed to efficiently serve a purpose, i.e. rooms are easy to find and easy to access. And there certainly aren't any traps.

Comment: @fgysin I'd direct you to the second half of my answer, which is a frame challenge against the idea that you need to use real world maps at all.

Comment: Two more examples of real world "dungeons" that were constructed for very practical purposes: 1) the ancient underground cities of Cappadocia (for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derinkuyu_underground_city) which residents used as sanctuaries from invaders, 2) and medieval salt mines found throughout Europe (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieliczka_Salt_Mine).

Answer (score 15):

### How To Host A Dungeon

[This game](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/299497/How-to-Host-a-Dungeon-2nd-Edition) may be the solution you're looking for. It is a solo game for building a dungeon that is supposed to present logical events occurring in the dungeon throughout different epochs of time through rolling on random tables. I've only purchased the game; I haven't played it, so I can't confirm that it results in a logical layout. This may depend on your intuitive grasp of interior space.

But, from a read through, it's not going to be one of those games where you roll a table to literally randomly generate each and every corridor. Each Age adds a new strata of the dungeon, that you build/draw as you play. **The game may help you to consider the logic and history behind how your dungeon is laid out.**

Comment: I've played this game a few times and noticed that dungeons can become big and complex. I want to add that this is easily solvable by just using a small section of the dungeon you create with this game for your RPG. Lastly, just looking at the event tables of this game and picking elements you like for your dungeon can also be a great way of designing dungeons.

Answer (score -1):

I see your question was asked about three years ago, so my answer may prove unneeded. Anyway, it may be helpful to create a dungeon with many chambers & corridors, but to have only one room which has *purpose*, and use that destination as an overall goal. The other areas of the dungeon would only be "ways" to achieve the final target. At least, this way you don't have to spend so much time coming up with reasons for every location. This idea for dungeon design is very common and normal, but works rather well.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.