# 1980's AD&D DM and player looking for some advice

Tags: dnd-5e

I am a child of AD&D of the 80's and my understanding that the game is in now a 5th edition. Would I find it difficult to enter a Roll20 or live tabletop from what I know?

Comment: Hi Lazabar, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Are you looking for a game in specifically AD&D or specifically D&D 5e, or either/whatever? Also, when you reach 20 rep, you can join us in [chat] where you'll find AD&D and D&D 5e players alike, as well as those of us who play different tabletop games entirely.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. While I appreciate the question's focus, there's no way  for readers to know what kind of *AD&D* experience *you* have, making this a difficult question to answer. Can you provide some background on your *AD&D* experiences (strictly by the rules, more freeform and storytelling than by-the-book, etc.)? Also, you might be better served by asking a similar question along the lines of *How different is* 5e *from* AD&D? (such a question, however, may be too broad). No matter what, though, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: [Related] [What are the main differences between Basic red box D&D (any version) and 5e?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84020)

Comment: Are you looking for a comparison/what's-new kind of overview? Or are you asking whether AD&D 1st edition games can be found on Roll20?

Comment: What do you know?  And what do you want?  Online for sure, 5e, 1e, what?

Comment: Also related [In what medium does D&D get played nowadays?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102380/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about the question's open/closed status has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70255/discussion-on-question-by-lazabar-sagamore-1980s-add-dm-and-player-looking-for).